# How does the system measure users' participation in Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, meta-reputation

In the [users page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users) there is an option which sorts Meta users by **participation**. How does the system measure this factor? By number of posts and comments? Or getting more upvotes and less downvotes in Meta posts? or something else?

Comment: In fact, you can find the same list for main site, too: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/participation-for-the-main-site/13154#13154

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The measure is the number of posts, comments, edits, and votes *cast* over the last 60 days.

This is explained  in the hover-text.

The [official source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145151/how-is-meta-participation-calculated/149097#149097) also mentions that deleted content is not taken into account and that self-edits do not count.

While it is not put on display one can also sort user on main by this criterion: https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation

Comment: I didn't know this interesting point. Thanks.

Comment: Can one sort users on Meta by reputation?! I think the system calculates people's reputation numbers to add their corresponding reputation based badges.

Comment: I examined http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation but it seems as same as main reputation rank not meta reputation.

Comment: I am not sure about that; but yes it seems for mortarboard, epic etc some value should be computed.

Comment: What I wrote about Meta reputation was based on the description of the **meta-reputation** tag which I added to this post.

Comment: @EdwardO'Connor The meta-reputation is hidden for all purposes except badges. There is a [Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/366302/users-by-approximate-meta-reputation?number=100) that calculates it *approximately* (not accounting for Community Wikis or daily reputation cap).

Comment: Wow. I am almost top 10. Tag badges are not really reputation based; they are vote based.